# What are Gibonacci identities

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, terminology

I was checking the table of contents of ***Proofs that Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof***  by Benjamin and Quinn and I saw that the second chapter is about Gibonacci and Lucas identities. My question is: What are Gibonacci identities? At first I thought it was a typo, but then I looked for Gibonacci identities and I got results so I eliminated that possibility. However, I could not find a definition of Gibonacci identities.

Comment: Poor Fibonacci... It is a pity that his name has been distorted so many times: Tribonacci, Tetranacci, Pentanacci, Hexanacci, Heptanacci, Octanacci, Enneanacci, Gibonacci...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authors tell you at the beginning of Chapter $2$ that *Gibonacci numbers* is short for *generalized Fibonacci numbers*, meaning sequences of numbers that satisfy the recurrence

$$G_n=G_{n-1}+G_{n-2}\,.$$

These include the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers — and infinitely many other sequences, defined by different initial values $G_0$ and $G_1$.

Comment: Did you mean $n-2$ where you typed $n+1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Ack! Absolutely. Fixed now.